# How can I tell my progress and the number of peers I'm connected to when using geth to download blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I'm running `get --fast --cache=1024` on my laptop as we speak, and I'd like to know some stats about how many peers I'm connected to at any given time.  I've been checking the size of my `chaindata` directory for a rough estimate of my progress, but is there any way to get this information from the geth process itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use console in second terminal.

```
geth attach
```

and then in the console:

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 27832,
  highestBlock: 3520007,
  startingBlock: 26025
}
> net.peerCount
9
```